# how to define a continuous function with special properties?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a hausdorff topological space and $C$ be a closed proper subset of $X$ , how to define a continuous function $f:X\to\Bbb{R}$  such that :

$f(x)=0$  for $x\in C$

$f(x)>0$ for $x\in X-C$

I wanna separate points from $C$ by a continiuous function!

Comment: If we are thinking about metric spaces, then $d(x,C)=\inf\{d(x,c)\colon c\in C\}$ does the trick. But, not all Hausdorff spaces are metrizable. Are
you sure this is possible? (I should mention that I have not thought
deeply about this).

Comment: @ArshGh ??? I posted a _proof_ that it's not possible 15 minutes before you posted that comment...

Comment: The constraints on $f$ imply that $C$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set because $f^{-1}[0,1/n)$ is open for $n\in N$, and $C=f^{-1}\{0\}=\cap_{n\in N}f^{-1}[0,1/n).$ Even an infinite compact normal space $X$ can have the property that NO infinite closed subset , except X itself, is $G_{\delta}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Urysohn's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma) implies that in a *normal* space you can separate points and closed sets by continuous functions; in fact you can separate disjoint closed sets.

But what you're trying to do is impossible in general. Not every Hausdorff space is normal, and what you're trying to do is not always possible in normal spaces. If $C$ and $f$ are as in your post then $C$ is a $G_\delta$ (a countable intersection of open sets). And there exist compact Hausdorff (hence normal) spaces $X$ with closed subsets $C$ such that $C$ is not a $G_\delta$. For example, let $X=\omega_1+1$ with the order topology, where $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal, and let $C=\{\omega_1\}$.

Comment: @ArshGh Are you aware that $[0,1]$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$?